# D3 - Update chart based on data keys

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, dataset

I am new to D3 and I would like to train myself on some scatterplot chart (based on the one from the NYT : [Student debt](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2012/05/13/business/student-debt-at-colleges-and-universities.html).

I managed to recreate a graph like this one : [Oklahoma Colleges](http://bl.ocks.org/darrenjaworski/raw/5544599/).

Now, I have much more entries than the Oklahoma chart, so my chart is not very readable and I would like to filter the data based on a button with which I can select to display only the "public" colleges or the "private" ones.

I have read many tutorials about the ENTER-UPDATE-EXIT methods but I still have some trouble in applying it practically on my case.

Assuming the following JSON file :

> [   {
>       "Id": 1,
>       "Name": "College A",
>       "Type": "Public"   },   {
>       "Id": 2,
>       "Name": "College B",
>       "Type": "Private"   },   {
>       "Id": 3,
>       "Name": "College C",
>       "Type": "Public"   },   {
>       "Id": 4,
>       "Name": "College D",
>       "Type": "Public"   },   {
>       "Id": 5,
>       "Name": "College E",
>       "Type": "Private"   },   {
>       "Id": 6,
>       "Name": "College F",
>       "Type": "Private"   }, ]

I would like to achieve the following algorithm :

```
button.on("change"){
If value == "public" :
  display data where data.type == "public"
Else
  display data where data.type == "private"
}
```

My first solution was to create a SVG each time I push the button (and erase the previous SVG) with the new dataset. But I think there is a much nicer way to do this :)

Can you help me ?
Thank you !

EDIT : following @sapote warrior answer -

Here what I do when I load the data :

```
d3.json("data.json", function(data) {

  //Coerce string to numbers
  ...
  dataset = data;
  ...
  //Add axis and legend

}
```

And when I click to one of the two button :

```
function update(input){

var data = [];
for(i in dataset) {
    if(dataset[i]["Type"] == input)
        data.push(dataset[i]);
}
test = data; //Global scope variable, to check if new data is here on the console
circles = svg.selectAll(".circle")
.data(data);
circles.exit().remove();
circles.enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class","circle")
  ...

}
```

But this doesn't work perfectly. Circles appear correctly when first click to any button, then they not all disappear when I click to the second button, and the new data doesn't seem to be correctly appended.

Hum, still have some issue understanding the enter-update-exit process ^^

**EDIT : Ok problem solved ! I have just made some mistakes when implementing the enter-update-exit methods. Did it with a reduced dataset to understand the issue and now it's clear in my mind :)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may be able to help you.  Assuming that your circles are already displayed on the SVG, one way to do it is build a new array of values when your button is clicked that are of type "Public" or "Private". Something like this:

```
publicButton.on("click", function() { 
newData = [];
for(i in existingDataArray) {
if(existingDataArray[i]["Type"] == "Public")
newData.push(existingDataArray[i]);
}
```

Now you can use this new data with the `.data().enter().exit().remove()` methods that you mentioned to append new data to your circle objects. After that you can remove those circles that aren't in the new data, and keep those that are.  Those that you keep you can then doing something to them like update their color or nothing at all if you like.  Sort of like this:

```
var circles = svg.selectAll("circle").data(newData);
circles.exit().remove();
circles.enter().attr("fill", ...);
}
```

Hopefully this helps some, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi ! Thank you, I will try to implement this as soon as I can :) Keep you updated !

Comment: Ok I have implemented your snippet of code. It is not working 100%. Assuming I have loaded to initial data into 'dataset' but I did not display anything at the initial loading. When I click to the button 'public' everything seems fine. However, when I then click to the button 'private', the previous nodes do not disappear and some new nodes do not appear. I have edited my question with the results.

Comment: Reading the tutorial from Mike Bostock at [link](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/)
If the new dataset is smaller than the old one, the surplus elements end up in the exit selection and get removed. If the new dataset is larger, the surplus data ends up in the enter selection and new nodes are added. If the new dataset is exactly the same size, then all the elements are simply updated with new positions, and no elements are added or removed.

I think the enteringData and exitingData are mixed. Do I need to identify each data with an ID (which I already have, how do I specify it to d3) ?

Comment: EDIT : Ok problem solved ! I have just made some mistakes when implementing the enter-update-exit methods. Did it with a reduced dataset to understand the issue and now it's clear in my mind :)

Comment: I'm glad you got this working!  Let me know if there is anything else I can help with.  Happy coding :)